# Get array within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to get the array value from the object I created but seems like that `obj.item` is not working to me. It always saying `undefined` here's my code::

```
$.each(componentSentenceArray, function(index,item) { 
          conole.log(item.item_name)

});
```

and here is my object

```
ingredient:
Array(3)
0:{item_name: "Albenza", uom_code: "", uom_desc: "", amount: ""}
1:{item_name: "Baclofen", uom_code: "", uom_desc: "", amount: ""}
2:{item_name: "Lasix", uom_code: "", uom_desc: "", amount: ""}


main_component:
Array(1)
0 :{item_name: "Lasix", uom_code: "", uom_desc: "", amount: ""}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code, instead of an image. And, I cannot find `item` key anywhere in the snapshot.

Comment: What are your array items? What are you trying to get?

Comment: @Mamun I updated the image bro.

Comment: @31piy I cannot replicate the actual code because the data is coming from DB

Comment: @kevin_marcus -- yes you can. Observe the network tab of your browser's developer tools. Copy the response of the API request and attach it in the question.

Comment: @kevin_marcus, update the question with actual array (not as image) as image preventing the array to copy.

Comment: I updated now my question bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var componentSentenceArray = {
    ingredient: [{
        item_name: "Albenza",
        uom_code: "",
        uom_desc: "",
        amount: ""
      },
      {
        item_name: "Baclofen",
        uom_code: "",
        uom_desc: "",
        amount: ""
      },
      {
        item_name: "Lasix",
        uom_code: "",
        uom_desc: "",
        amount: ""
      }
    ],
    main_component: [{
      item_name: "Lasix",
      uom_code: "",
      uom_desc: "",
      amount: ""
    }]
  };

  $.each(componentSentenceArray, function(index, item) {
    $.each(item, function(index, item1) {
      console.log(item1.item_name);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This should work for you. You are having array list inside and object which you should loop again to access its variable.

```
  $.each(componentSentenceArray, function(index,item) { 
    $.each(item, function(index,item1) { 
      console.log(item1.item_name);    
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(componentSentenceArray, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key)
    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        console.log('index', data)
    })
})
```

this will work!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(componentSentenceArray, function(index,item) { 
     $.each(item, function(index, arrayItem) {
       console.log(arrayItem.item_name)
     })
});
```

This should help